# Как перевести строку в массив?

Tags: массивы, php, строки

Есть строка типа:

```
({"result": "silver":0,"red":1,"blue":0,"green":0,"orange":0,"white":0,"black":0,"gray":0}})
```

Как мне ее превратить во что-нибудь типа массива, чтоб удобно было перемещаться по данным.  Например:

```
foreach ($array as $color => $state) {
  if ($state) {
    .....
  } else {
    .....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно вам поможет [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
<?php
$a = '({"result":{"silver":0,"red":1,"blue":0,"green":0,"orange":0,"white":0,"black":0,"gray":0}})';
$b = json_decode(preg_replace('/^\(/','',preg_replace('/\)$/','',$a)));
foreach ($b["status"] as $color => $state) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: в ответе выдает "NULL"

Comment: Круглые скобки уберите, и всё будет гуд...

Comment: Спасиб, все получилось ))) в регулярных выражениях я не силен, верней совсем не силен ))) поэтому просто присвоил "NULL" первому и последнему символу строки и сделал trim.

Comment: @grisha, substr($a, 1, -1);

Comment: Можно сделать еще круче:

    $b = json_decode(trim($a, "() \t"));

Answer (score 0):

это не строка а хеш, еще и не хватает "{" после 'result': 
так что копать вам в сторону хешей в php.
в javascript примерно так

```
var hash = {"result": {"silver":0,"red":1,"blue":0,"green":0,"orange":0,"white":0,"black":0,"gray":0}};
hash.result.silver; // => 0
for(var i in hash.result) 
 hash.result[i]; // => 0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: Такого хэша, как в Перле, в PHP нету. Тут есть ассоциативные массивы. А приведенные данные обычные JSON-данные.

Comment: это пример хеша в javascript, и да, просто привел пример, думая что в php можно сделать по аналогии.